# Tabulate text within caption

Tags: floats, errors, captions

I would like to tabulate text within a caption.
See below what I obtain with my code:

```
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6in]{topfigure.png}
\includegraphics[width=6in]{bottomfigure.png}
\rule{35em}{0.5pt}
\caption{\begin{tabular}{ll} 
            (top figure)    & Legend of the top figure. \\
            (bottom figure) & The legend of the bottom figure is aligned with the previous one
            \end{tabular}}
\label{fig9} 
\end{figure}
```

[image: Final wanted result]

It actually works, although it gives me the following error message:

> ! Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }.
>   
>   \par
>   l.183 \end{tabular}}

Any idea how to avoid this error message?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `\begin` and `\end` commands are fragile, in a caption you have to say `\protect\begin{tabular}[t]{ll}` and `\protect\end{tabular}` (the `[t]` is for better vertical alignment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that the `tabular` doesn't want to transfer "easily" into the LoF. It would also not make sense to have a `tabular` construction in the LoF, since the figures won't be there to understand any reference to top/bottom. As such, my suggestion would be to use the optional argument for `\caption[<LoF>]{<caption>}` (even though you might not use it in the end):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\captionrule}{\rule{.8\linewidth}{0.5pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}

  \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-b}

  \captionrule

  \caption[some ToC entry]{\begin{tabular}{ll@{}} 
              (top figure)    & Legend of the top figure. \\
              (bottom figure) & The legend of the bottom figure.
              \end{tabular}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This setup allows you to now also play with the vertical alignment of the `tabular`. Using `\begin{tabular}[t]{..}` you'll achieve the following layout:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Werner!
Thanks to you I learned another functionality of Latex!